# Solving a PDE with its boundary condition expressed as a piecewise function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear, piecewise

All I want to do is solve the PDE

```
pde = D[y[x, t], t] + y[x, t] D[y[x, t], x] == 0
```

with the boundary condition expressed as a piecewise function, say,

```
init = Piecewise[{{2 - x^2, Abs[x] < 1}}, 1]
```

I tried to evaluate the following

```
sol = DSolve[{pde, y[x, 0] == init}, y[x, t], {x, t}]
```

but my computer ran for about 20 mins and then crashed.

I don't think that this should be the most difficult problem to solve, but apparently Mathematica just hates this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: maybe I am missing something. But your post title says "Boundary conditions" but then in the code you write `y[x, 0] == init`. How could `y[x,0]` be a boundary condition when `t=0` there? Would this not be an initial conditions instead? At least this is how I learned it.

Comment: isn't your initial conditions the same as `init = Piecewise[{{2 - x^2, x < 1 && x > -1}}, 1]` ?  When written this way, M returns right away. It does not hang. But it still can't solve it. The issue is using `Abs[x]`, which makes it hard for it to find the integral internally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although `DSolve` cannot solve this problem directly, it can make progress if given some assistance.  First consider the corresponding problem with no boundary condition.

```
sol = DSolve[pde, y[x, t], {x, t}]
(* Solve[y[x, t] == C[1][x - t y[x, t]], y[x, t]] *)
```

In other words, `y[x,t]` satisfies the equation

```
sol[[1]]
(* y[x, t] == C[1][x - t y[x, t]] *)
```

where `C[1]` is an arbitrary function of `x - t y[x, t]`.  Now, apply the boundary condition by considering

```
sol[[1]] /. t -> 0
(* y[x, 0] == C[1][x] *)
```

Comparing this with the definition of `init`, we have

```
y[x, t] == (init /. x -> x - t y[x, t])
(* y[x, t] ==  Piecewise[{{2 - (x - t y[x, t])^2, Abs[x - t y[x, t]] < 1}}, 1]*)
```

Thus, for `Abs[x - t y[x, t]] < 1`,

```
s = Solve[y[x, t] == 2 - (x - t y[x, t])^2, y[x, t]] // Flatten
    (* {y[x, t] -> (-1 + 2 t x - Sqrt[1 + 8 t^2 - 4 t x])/(2 t^2), 
        y[x, t] -> (-1 + 2 t x + Sqrt[1 + 8 t^2 - 4 t x])/(2 t^2) *)
```

and otherwise,

```
(* y[x, t] == 1 *)
```

*Corrected plots*: The first solution can be plotted by

```
Plot3D[Piecewise[{{s[[1, 2]], Abs[x - t s[[1, 2]]] < 1}}, 1], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}, 
    PlotPoints -> 500, AxesLabel -> {x, t, y}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]]
```

[image]

and similarly for the second.

[image]

It is, perhaps, not surprising that `DSolve` could not obtain this solution directly.

Comment: @Akku14  The first solution is identically `1` in the limit `t == 0`.  The second solution is `2 - x^2` for `Abs[x] < 1` and `1` otherwise in the limit `t == 0`.  This can be verified symbolically using `Series` or numerically by setting `t` to any value very close to zero, for instance, `10^-5`.  Note that, because the PDE is nonlinear, linear combinations of the two solutions are not also solutions.

Comment: I probably should have written initial condition rather than  boundary solution, that is my fault. I was trying to solve a quasilinear first order PDE Cauchy problem with this, and I had problems with NDSolve saying I needed more initial/boundary condition. Isn't it a theorem that for any nth order PDE, we need n initial conditions to find a unique solution? why did NDsolve want more? Just as an add on question.

Comment: Also, when I copy and paste this code into Mathematica, a Part error occurs where it says that certain points of the graph do not exist, and I get an empty graph, so I'm a bit confused. It has to suppress Part::partw during the calculation

Comment: @dragon18456  I copied and pasted the code in my answer, along with your code for `pde` and `init` into a fresh notebook, and everything worked fine.  With respect to your earlier question, `NDSolve` needs boundary as well as initial conditions, probably one of each.  Finally, I just realized that your `pde` is [Burger's equation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveLinearAndQuasiLinearFirstOrderPDEs.html).  Your `init` makes the problem quite interesting, of course.

Comment: what would you do for an init of e^{-1/x} x>0, 0 x<= 0, the methods available to Solve fail here, should I use NDSolve to see the solutions?

Comment: @dragon18456 `NDSolve` probably would work, although you will need a boundary condition as well as an initial condition (which should not be hard).  Alternatively, you could use `FindRoot` to invert the solution equation on an array of `{t, x}` values and then plot the result using `ListPlot3D`.  You might wish to try the `NDSolve` and `FindRoot` approaches on your original problem above just to test them.

Comment: Can I try solving the PDE for a implicit piece wise equation for y[x,t]=e^{-1/{x-t y[x,t]}} when x-t y[u,t]>0, 0 else. Trying to use ContourPlot3D for this equation just slowly destroys mathematica

Comment: @dragon18456 Yes, you can.  In fact, you should.  Note also, that you could try the approach I mentioned my last comment, using `ListContourPlot3D`, although it will require a very big array for good resolution.  I recommend you use a less expensive plot routine, like `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: @dragon18456  Although `Solve` cannot invert your newer expression to obtain `y` as a function of `x` and `t`, I believe that it can obtain `x` as a function of `y` and `t`, which then can be plotted with `ParametricPlot3D`.  Applying the `Piecewise` condition may take some thought, however.